# ASP .Net Core localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created an ASP.NET Core Project and chose an empty project rather than the default template. I use Visual Studio For Mac. I added a few NuGet packages, see image,[image]

Here's an image of my Startup.cs file 
[image]

Lastly, an image of my Program.cs File
[image]

When i run the project I get this error "localhost is currently unable to handle this request. Http Error 500". Since I can't configure IIS on a Mac (Unless there's a way?) I can't seem to figure out what's causing this error. Maybe I'm missing something on the Startup.cs File? What might be cause?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when the application root did not contain a web.config file.
Check it and create one if needed.